# Is there a way to map over the data just received through an API call and show all the charecter names on the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made an API call to a starwars http by using the react fetch method. i have received the data but cant seem to be able to display the name of all the characters once i map over the data.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
          loading: false,
          character: []
      }
  };


  componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({loading: true})
      fetch("https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=2")
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
              this.setState({
                  loading: false,
                  character: data
              })
              console.log(this.state.character.results);        
          })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className='dabba'>

        <ul>
            {
                this.state.character.results.map( (person, id) => {
                    return <li key={id}>{person.name}</li>
                } )
            }
        </ul>

      </div>
    );
  }




}
```

Comment: What is `this.state.character.results`?  Where does the `results` property come from?

Comment: so the information that comes in has an Array that's called results and holds 10 objects that I am trying to map over and get the name of each object. which would also be the name of the characters in the starwar movies

Comment: Every time I map over the {this.state.charecter.results} i get the TypeError: cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

Comment: Hi, the api is returning a 503 error, which is not within my capacity to fix. Beyond that, you're getting an error because when your component renders initially, it's trying to run `map` over something that it has not yet finished fetching. In your initial state, you want to set `loading` to `true`. You'd then flip that to `false` once your api call resolves. Then, in your `render()` method, in the `<ul>` element, you can do a check to see if `loading` is true or not, something like: `{ this.state.loading ? <li>loading...</li> : /* your call to map here */ }`

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  That worked.

Answer (score -1):

I'm getting a 503 response from that address when using fetch. When you are logging the response, are you getting something valid? If not, map won't work on an undefined object because it has no key for'response'

Comment: I am getting a 503 as well now, but before i was getting the data i was requesting which was star wars character names and properties.

Comment: I am receiving data now which is basically an Array with 10 objects within in and each object has a name and height/weight which i am trying to access